# yum missing requirement that is already installed

Tags: unix, redhat, rhel7

I'm running rhel7.  When I try to yum install glibc, it looks like it's already installed:

```
yum install glibc
Package matching glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.5.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
```

But when I thin try to install glibc-headers, it fails at the following error:

```
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7_6.5.x86_64 (prod1)
       Requires: glibc = 2.17-260.el7_6.5
```

I've searched around and can't figure out what's going on.  I've clean installed glibc.  The closest I've come is to this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1717626, but the advice didn't help.

How can I figure out the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall glibc and reinstall it :

```
# yum remove glibc
# yum install glibc
```

Comment: Be careful, a lot of packages depend on glibc and they will be removed